# As3 City Simulation Game Engine

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, game-engine

I am planning to create a Flash AS3 game that is like SimCity. Or something like the Facebook game [Youtopia](http://apps.facebook.com/you-topia/). http://apps.facebook.com/you-topia/

Any good AS3 game engines?? I do not plan to create multiplayer games, just single player ones, and the player can load and save the city. The player has to meet a certain objective within a time limit (like 20 years). Also each building has different sizes (like 1x2, 2x2) so the engine must detect which tile is occupied. The map will be have a 10x10 size, so I don't need to worry about performance.

I have seen Flixel but the games gallery doesn't look so promising. Flashpunk and PushButton looks interesting.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to make a game this big I would recommend you to make your own engine on top of other ones.
'Game' is not that specific so we can have game engines like flixel.

I would look at this http://code.google.com/p/as3isolib/
It is nice isometric library for as3.

Comment: Thats a nice library. Although there are not so many tutorials on it.

Answer (score 1):

maybe Yogurt3D must be helpful for you. They claim it is possible to create in-browser 3D games without any plug-in installation. Its animation system, model formats, exporter plug-ins for modelling tools, scene hierarchy and scene management structure, and that it is developed with a game developer perspective, makes Yogurt3D a powerful tool for 3D game developers.

http://www.yogurt3d.com

Answer (score 0):

Youtopia was written using PushButton Engine before it was acquired by Playdom/Disney.

For Youtopia, they rolled their own isometric library from scratch.

As for additional Isometric libraries, as3isolib is a fantastic library as is the up and coming IsoKit http://lunarraid.blogspot.com/2011/07/isokit-brief-history.html